# Problems when installing python Polyglot package on virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, polyglot

I am trying to install several packages on a virtual environment on a Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.6). I have successfully installed polyglot (version 16.7.4). Everything works fine until I launched Python (version 3.6).

This is what I get as a result of a try to import text from polyglot.

```
>>> import polyglot
>>> from polyglot import text
sh: grep: command not found
sh: sysctl: command not found
sh: sw_vers: command not found
sh: grep: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<WORKING DIRECTORY>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/text.py", line 9, in <module>
from polyglot.detect import Detector, Language
  File "<WORKING DIRECTORY>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .base import Detector, Language
  File "<WORKING DIRECTORY>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/base.py", line 11, in <module>
from icu import Locale
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icu'
>>>
```

To create the virtual environment I ran the venv module as a script with the directory path.

Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The author of `polyglot` has forgotten to list [requirements](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/blob/master/requirements.txt) in `setup.py` so `pip install polyglot` doesn't install them automatically. Please report the bug to the issue tracker.

Meanwhile dowload polyglot sources and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks the problem seems that it doesn't install PyICU, which is required. This error comes up (even after downloading the source):   ./common.h:105:10: fatal error: 'unicode/utypes.h' file not found

Comment: To compile PyICU you need to [compile ICU](https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu#building-pyicu) first.